# How to use LibreOffice API (UNO) with Python + Windows?

Tags: python, libreoffice, openoffice.org, uno

This question is focused on Windows + LibreOffice + Python 3.

I've installed LibreOffice (6.3.4.2), also 
 `pip install unoconv` and `pip install unotools`  (`pip install uno` is another unrelated library), but still I get this error after `import uno`:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'uno'

**More generally, and as an example of use of UNO, how to open a .docx document with LibreOffice UNO and export it to PDF?**

I've searched extensively on this since a few days, but I haven't found a reproducible sample code working on Windows:

- headless use of `soffice.exe`, see my question+answer [Headless LibreOffice very slow to export to PDF on Windows (6 times slow than on Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61447666/headless-libreoffice-very-slow-to-export-to-pdf-on-windows-6-times-slow-than-on) and the notes on the answer: it "works" with `soffice.exe --headless ...` but something closer to a COM interaction (Component Object Model) would be useful for many applications, thus this question here
- Related [forum post](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=36370&p=166783), and [LibreOffice: Programming with Python Scripts](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.3/en-US/text/sbasic/python/python_programming.html?&DbPAR=WRITER&System=WIN), but the way uno should be installed on Windows, with Python, is not detailed; also [Detailed tutorial regarding LibreOffice to Python macro writing, especially for Calc](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/49125/detailed-tutorial-regarding-libreoffice-to-python-macro-writing-especially-for-calc/)
- I've also tried this (unsuccessfully): [Getting python to import uno / pyuno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24965406/getting-python-to-import-uno-pyuno/28985524#28985524):

  ```
  import os
  os.environ["URE_BOOTSTRAP"] = r"vnd.sun.star.pathname:C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\fundamental.ini"
  os.environ["PATH"] += r";C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program"
  import uno
  ```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to interact with LibreOffice, start an instance listening on a socket. I don't use COM much, but I think this is the equivalent of the COM interaction you asked about. This can be done most easily on the command line or using a shell script, but it can also work with a system call using a time delay and subprocess.

```
chdir "%ProgramFiles%\LibreOffice\program\"
start soffice -accept=socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;
```

Next, run the installation of python that comes with LibreOffice, which has `uno` installed by default.

```
"C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\python.exe"
>> import uno
```

If instead you are using an installation of Python on Windows that was not shipped with LibreOffice, then getting it to work with UNO is *much* more difficult, and I would not recommend it unless you enjoy hacking.

Now, here is all the code. In a real project, it's probably best to organize into classes, but this is a simplified version.

```
import os
import uno
from com.sun.star.beans import PropertyValue
def createProp(name, value):
    prop = PropertyValue()
    prop.Name = name
    prop.Value = value
    return prop

localContext = uno.getComponentContext()
resolver = localContext.ServiceManager.createInstanceWithContext(
    "com.sun.star.bridge.UnoUrlResolver", localContext)
ctx = resolver.resolve(
    "uno:socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;"
    "StarOffice.ComponentContext")
smgr = ctx.ServiceManager
desktop = smgr.createInstanceWithContext(
    "com.sun.star.frame.Desktop", ctx)
dispatcher = smgr.createInstanceWithContext(
    "com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper", ctx)
filepath = r"C:\Users\JimStandard\Desktop\Untitled 1.docx"
fileUrl = uno.systemPathToFileUrl(os.path.realpath(filepath))
uno_args = (
    createProp("Minimized", True),
)
document = desktop.loadComponentFromURL(
    fileUrl, "_default", 0, uno_args)
uno_args = (
    createProp("FilterName", "writer_pdf_Export"),
    createProp("Overwrite", False),
)
newpath = filepath[:-len("docx")] + "pdf"
fileUrl = uno.systemPathToFileUrl(os.path.realpath(newpath))
try:
    document.storeToURL(fileUrl, uno_args)  # Export
except ErrorCodeIOException:
    raise
try:
    document.close(True)
except CloseVetoException:
    raise
```

Finally, since speed is a concern, using a listening instance of LibreOffice can be slow. To do this faster, move the code into a macro. [APSO](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/apso-alternative-script-organizer-for-python) provides a menu to organize Python macros. Then call the macro like this:

```
soffice "vnd.sun.star.script:myscript.py$name_of_maindef?language=Python&location=user"
```

In macros, obtain the document objects from `XSCRIPTCONTEXT` rather than the resolver.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I'm going to try this. *If instead you are using an installation of Python on Windows that was not shipped with LibreOffice, then getting it to work with UNO is much more difficult*: oh ok, this is what I was trying indeed! In fact I wanted to use my standard python (not the one shipped with LibreOffice), because I already have all my libraries there, etc.

Comment: Yes, I understand why you would want to do that, but it's probably not a good idea.

Comment: @JimK please share the _much more difficult_ way

Comment: @deostroll: It's linked in the question, where the OP wrote "I've also tried this (unsuccessfully)."